# eigenvalues of the sum of a diagonal and diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a matrix with a nonzero entry $t_0$ in the (1,1) entry and padded with zeros everywhere else; and let $B$ be a diagonalizable matrix, such that $VBV^T$ is diagonal. Is there anything we can say about the eigenvalues of $A+B$ if we know the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

What if $A$ is merely a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general not much. Consider for instance the matrix 
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
with characteristic polynomial $x^{2} - a^{2}$, so over the complex numbers, say, the eigenvalues are $\pm a$. (We have to take $a \ne 0$ to have it diagonalizable.) Add your $A$, you get
$$
A + B = \begin{bmatrix}t_{0}&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
with characteristic polynomial $x^{2} - t_{0} x - a^{2}$, which as $t_{0}$ ranges over the complex numbers, has as roots all pairs of complex numbers $u,v$ such that $u v = a^{2}$.

Even worse examples can be constructed, will possibly post later.

Comment: Since $VBV^T=\Delta$ you know $B$ is symmetric.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1, I hadn't noticed that, thanks a lot! Should have been fixed now.

Comment: In the case I am working on the dimensions of $A$ and $B$ tend to infinity and the entries in $B$ are being drawn randomly from a certain distribution. So worst case examples should be avoided. But it's enlightening to learn that my naive approach is useless here.

Answer (score 0):

Observation: The matrix $A$ is rank 1.

Thus by Cauchy Interlacing Theorem the eigenvalues of $B$ and $A + B$ *interlace.*
This does not give precise information about the eigenvalues, rather ranges where the new eigenvalues will lie.

Hope this helps in your application.